Rails 8 migration failing due to opaque deprecation description
Migrating from rails 7.1 to 7.2, the following warning was issued:
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::ProxyObject is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 8.0.
Use Ruby's built-in BasicObject instead.
 (called from <main> at .../config/application.rb:7)

which corresponds to the uncommented line
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

However, this reader does not make any connection between the config line nor the warning.
Nothing in this regard in the release notes for upgrading addresses this specifically.
The upgrade to 8 upon rails app:update returns
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/basic_object (LoadError)
[...  and a bit later a curious entry ...]
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/proxy_object (LoadError)

How can I be enlightened here?  How can this configuration line be changed to use BasicObject ?

How is the migration failing? If you are just getting a warning - it’s likely something that will be fixed in 8.0.

yes, you are right, ther is no data on the failure (stayed focused on the deprecation warning).  question amended.

This is a red herring. Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) is just requiring the gems in your gemfile. Bundler neither can nor should fix issues with those gems. Since its the entry point for your gems it will pop up in the stack trace if any issues occur when requiring the gems. You'll have to dig deeper to find the actual culprit. If the complete stack trace doesn't tell you anything start commenting out gems until you find it.

Alternatively you could search your installed gems for references to ActiveSupport::ProxyObject. grep -r "ActiveSupport::ProxyObject" $(bundle show --paths) .

Yes I had realised that, as stock new rails 8.0 applications come with that line.

Two issues were raised in the upgrade process.  They happen to be upstream to the rails update function, but the messaging was unclear.
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      stringio (>= 0)
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      psych (>= 4.0.0)

while the former disappears when running gem cleanup stringio,
the latter keeps proposing itself after running gem cleanup psych:
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 5.2.2
      - 5.1.2
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Clean up complete
[xxx] gal % gem cleanup psych
Cleaning up installed gems...
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 5.2.2
      - 5.1.2
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Clean up complete
[xxx] gal % gem cleanup psych
Cleaning up installed gems...
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 5.2.2
      - 5.1.2

rails version would still indicate 8.0.1 though...
An examination of Gemfile.lock reveals the conflict that is not resolved by the cleanup task.
• delete Gemfile.lock
• run bundle
• run bundle update rails
errors disappeared and application can run.
As @max comment points out,
•    the deprecation warning is misleading
•    rdoc and psych dependencies leave users in the lurch: either some upstream spec is off. I would add that the suggestion message is incomplete.
